# asp.net data entry form

Tags: asp.net

I want to build a form where users can enter some data in a few text boxes and click the "Add" button and have the the data appear in a grid or something like it.  They need to be able to enter multiple rows.

Then when they are done they can click the "Save" button to save the data to the database.

How do I get the data from from the text boxes into the "grid"?

EDIT

Here's what I have so far

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Employee");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc1);
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Category");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc2);
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Description");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc3);
    DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("P/S/N");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc4);
    DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("Hours");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc5);
    DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("WeekEnding");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(dc6);

}
protected void btnAddToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    DataRow row = myDataTable.NewRow();// i'm getting error here sayind myDataTable does not exist

    row["Employee"] = LoginName1.ToString();
    row["Category"] = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
    row["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;
    row["P/S/N"] = ddlPSN.SelectedValue;
    row["Hours"] = ddlHours.SelectedValue;
    row["WeekEnding"] = txtWeekEnding.Text;

    myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: is this homework? Even if it's not... what have you tried so far?

Comment: no, i"m trying to replace timesheet system at my work that currently uses excel spreadsheets.  I want people to be able to enter their hours in categories with descriptions and be able to review all their hours for the week before saving.

I've found some information on creating datatables and data rows and then binding them to the grid.  I'm trying to work that out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok your first problem from your comment:

```
i'm getting error here sayind myDataTable does not exist
```

Is because you defined your table in the `Page_Load` and then it goes out of scope at the end of the function.  It sounds like you don't understand the basic concepts of ASP.NET and what you are trying to do.

Here is a quick and dirty untested solution to your problem but I must stress that you should try and understand why this solution works before trying to extend it or do more in ASP.NET.  I hope my 10 minutes of my time helps you get a good start into understanding C# and ASP.NET.

```
[Serializable]
public class YourData
{
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string P_S_N { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public string WeekEnding { get; set; }
}

// Used to add your list of data to the viewstate cache
// (There are other ways to store data between posts but I am trying to keep it simple)
public void SetYourCachedData(List<YourData> data)
{
    ViewState["YourDataCache"] = data;
}

// Used to get your save data so far
public List<YourData> GetYourCachedData()
{
    return ViewState["YourDataCache"] == null ?
        new List<YourData>() : (List<YourData>)(ViewState["YourDataCache"]);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do nothing
}

protected void btnAddToGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the data and store it in the ViewState to cache it between post backs
    // Assuming one record added with each click.
    List<YourData> data = GetYourCachedData();
    data.Add(new YourData()
    {
        Employee = LoginName1.ToString(),
        Category = ddlCategory.SelectedValue,
        Description = txtDescription.Text,
        P_S_N = ddlPSN.SelectedValue,
        Hours = ddlHours.SelectedValue,
        WeekEnding = txtWeekEnding.Text
    });            

    // You can bind to any type of collection easily.
    // You don't need to use a DataTable with a GridView
    yourGrid.DataSource = data;
    yourGrid.DataBind();

    SetYourCachedData(data);
}

protected void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pull data from the ViewState cache
    List<YourData> data = GetYourCachedData();

    // Now iterate through data to save it to your database...
    // look this up if you don't know how as this is a lot more work.
}
```

Comment: I'm studying your solution and do want to understand it.  I haven't worked with Lists or ViewState before so I will research those topics to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to set the output object's datasource and bind it.

I.e.:

```
myGrid.datasource = myDataTable
myGrid.databind()
```

And as Kelsey says -- keep your datatable in scope.

a public dim right above your page_load would be easier, if you just want to try it out.  Otherwise, the separate class approach is a good way to go.